# Label appearing conditionally

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a label appear if the condition of my entry (textbox) is met. Unfortunately I cannot see anything when I am pressing the button on the testing. Here is what I have:

```
from tkinter import *

main= Tk()
firstname=Entry(main).place(x=30, y=50)

def register():
    if any(i.isdigit() for i in firstname.get())== True:
        print (Label(main,text='no numbers please').place(x=30, y=180))
    else:
        print(Label(main, text='pass').place(x=40, y=170))

register=Button(main,text='REGISTER', command= lambda :register).place(x=300, y=200)
```

Comment: The lambda needs to be `lambda: register()`, or simply remove the lambda: `command=register`. Your command will fail, but this explains why you don't see anything.

Comment: @BryanOakley  ` 'NoneType' object is not callable` this what I get

Comment: Yes. Due to this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1101750/7432

Comment: @BryanOakley I dont think so, I think it is because `register` is the button which became `None` but what the OP wants to call is the func, so rename the button or the func to something else.

Comment: @CoolCloud: yes, you are correct. There are three problems with this code, not just two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least three problems with your code. The first is in how you define the button's command:

```
register=Button(main,text='REGISTER', command= lambda :register)
```

When you do `command=lambda: register`, you're telling the button "when you're clicked run the code `register`". `register` all by itself does nothing. Since `register` is (supposed to be) a function, you need to call it like `register()` inside the lambda.

Since you aren't passing any values to the function, the `lambda` is completely unnecessary. Instead, just directly reference the function: `command=register` *without* the parenthesis.

The second problem is that you've used the name `register` to be two different things: a function and a reference to a widget. Because of the ordering of the code, `command=register` or `command=lambda: register()` will try to call the button rather than the function.

The third problem is a [very, *very* common mistake](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1101750/7432). In python, when you do `x = y().z()`, `x` is given the value of `z()`. Thus, `register = Button(...).pack(...)` returns the value of `pack(...)` and `pack` (and `grid` and `place`) always returns `None`.

Therefore, you've set `register` to `None`, and when you try to call it you get `NoneType object is not callable`.

In addition to fixing the `command`, you need to pick a different name for either the function or the button. And you should not be calling `place` (or `pack` or `grid`) in-line with creating the widget. They should be separate steps.

So, putting that all together, you need to define `firstname` like this so that `firstname` is not `None`:

```
firstname=Entry(main)
firstname.place(x=30, y=50)
```

And then you need to define the button like this:

```
register_button = Button(main,text='REGISTER', command= register)
register_button.place(x=300, y=200)
```

Comment: very well explained. I understood a great deal. However when I try to run  it following these instructions `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`and when I remove it I have `NoneType object is not iterable `

Comment: @Camue: then you didn't follow everything in the answer. `NoneType object ...` errors mean that something is `None` when it shouldn't be. You simply have to step back through your code to see where you defined the variable, and figure out why it's being set to `None`.